# How to export music files of a playlist into one folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

Over a period of time I have assembled mulitple playlists. I would like to export the songs of these playlists into corresponding folders. I have tried looking into windows media player but couldn't find any such option.

Comment: So you mean you want to physically move the songs into separate folders based on the entries in a set of playlists? This should be something that it easy enough to script with AutoIt, batch, python, perl, vbscript, etc. It is pretty much just reading a set of text documents and moving or copying files accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

With [Foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) you can drag the songs from a playlist to a folder.

Comment: +1 for foobar2000, which also scales pretty well for large playlists. Why get a separate tool if your music player can already do it?

Comment: Thanks, It works seamlessly. Just drag your playlist into Foobar and then drag the selected files to any folder on windows. I checked Foobar with **VirusTotal** and [no engine detected malware](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/573d98c2cb620f99b618ebf0a428975b9283c8a99b5ef2d41e13defdfa03f82a/detection).